# SwiftUI, can't load the image by URL with PageTabViewStyle

Tags: swift, swiftui, kingfisher

Hi I'm struggling with the problem that I can't load image in TabView

I wanted to make page view so I try to use TabView() and PageTabViewStyle.

and I also use KingFisher library to load image by URL.

When I wrote code like below, this code is not working. :

```
TabView() {
        KFImage(URL(string: <ADDRESS for IMAGE>)!)
               .resizable()
               .clipped()
               .frame(width: width_screen, height: height_banner, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

I had doubt about KFImage but if the KFImage scope is out of TabView(), it works well. When I wrote code like below, it works well.

```
var body: some View {
    TabView() {
        ...
    }

    KFImage(URL(string: "<ADDRESS for IMAGE>")!)
                        .resizable()
                        .clipped()
                        .frame(width: width_screen, height: height_banner, alignment: .topLeading)
}
```

I wonder how to present image in this tabview. Or I should construct custom view to make paging view.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is about async operation. I come up with this solution;

in view:

```
@State private var image: UIImage? = nil
```

in body:

```
TabView() {
        Image(uiImage: image ?? UIImage(named: "defaultImage")!)
            .resizable()
            .clipped()
            .frame(width: 250, height:200, alignment: .topLeading)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                fetchImage()
            })
            
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

*I used "UIImage(named: "defaultImage")!" and "width: 250, height:200" but you can replace them with yours.

in view:

```
    private func fetchImage() {
    if let url = URL(string: imageUrl) {
        KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url) { result in
            let image = try? result.get().image
            if let image = image {
                self.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution without using Kingfisher would be like;

```
    TabView() {
        if let url = URL(string: imageUrl) {
            if let imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data) {
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .clipped()
                        .frame(width: 250, height:200, alignment: .topLeading)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

This works well.

Comment: Thank you. It works well. But it's sad that it makes error when I wrapped this in ForEach statement. +) Ah you added some more answers! I will check it

Comment: you are welcome. feel free to ask if you still have issues.

Comment: I would try to use ForEach statement to make series of images from URL list but it returns error(coordinator.collectionview : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION). I guess I use viewModel.{something} for ForEach(0..<viewModel.{something}, id: \.self) makes problem. (viewModel is ObservedObject.) Is there any solution that I can fetch data from ObservedData without crash?

Comment: I solve this problem with refresh TabView by .id()! thank you